# Excel calculation engine

Tags: microsoft-excel

### Context

I currently work on a web application which is intended to simplify filling in complex Excel workbooks.

An average workbook in question would usually have a number of tabs (worksheets) with complex Excel formulas utilizing dropdowns, SUMIFs, SUMPRODUCT, INDIRECT, OFFSET, MATCH, INDEX and many other excel formulas.

### System design

User input from front end gets sent to backend which has calculation module (small sub-set of what you would quickly model in Excel workbook - make one row cells be % of another row cells etc).

### Problem

The holistic design above worked just fine and code base was created for steadily adding new calculation methods and dependencies. However given the market feedback it appears that workbooks where the application is supposed to simplify work, would come from client. And as opposed to original assumption (single model) it now appears there going to be myriad of computation models represented as Excel workbooks.

Apparently current system design becomes rigid for moving fast with all the way new models.

### Possible solution

Consume client model in the form of Excel instead of replicating all the calculations in code. Identify inputs (Excel cells which drive calculations) and outputs (results of calculations). Let users continue using the application UI to provide inputs in a user friendly and fancy way and then set the user's inputs into the Excel model to corresponding cells (necessary meta description of Excel workbook for that is assumed to be in the application).

### Question

What would be proper solution for high-performant  implementation of the possible solution?

My thoughts are around utilizing an Excel calculation engine (not a parser but one that really runs formulas).

### What I tried so far

- SpreadJS - supports all necessary functions. But does not work in server environment (browser only solution). Proprietary.
- Hyperformula - works in server environment. But does not support certain Excel functions (INDIRECT), partially supports some other functions (f.e. OFFSET).

Both solutions take a long time loading a workbook (which is a blocker for using such engines in a performant application requiring fast user responses).